# Prove $\lim_{a \to \infty} \frac{\sin a}{a} = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

> Prove $\lim_{a \to \infty} \frac{\sin a}{a} = 0$.

Attempt:

> $|\frac{\sin a}{a} - 0| \leq |\frac{1}{a}|$ so $\frac{1}{a} < \epsilon \implies a > \frac{1}{\epsilon} $
>
> So $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N=\frac{1}{\epsilon} : \forall a> N \implies |\frac{\sin a}{a} - 0| \leq |\frac{1}{a}| = \frac{1}{a} < \epsilon $
> which means $\lim_{a \to \infty} \frac{\sin a}{a} = 0$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Note that $1/\epsilon$ may not be an integer (not sure if you mean to implicitly assume so by assigning it to a variable called $N$). Also,  $|1/x|$ seems out of place in the last chain of inequalities. (What is $x$?)

Comment: note that $|\sin(x)|\le 1$